# Not rightly shown quotes

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a problem to shown quotes in html from php script.
This code:

```
$str = '<select name=\'image\' OnChange=\'javascript:document.forms[0].showimage.src="' . $imgdir_ . '"+this.value+""\'>';
```

Result:

```
<select name="image" onchange="javascript:document.forms[0].showimage.src=&quot;http://bitmirror.net/pic/categories/&quot;+this.value+&quot;&quot;">
```

What is the wrong please?

Thank you

Comment: How do you print this variable?

Comment: What's supposed to be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using `htmlspecialchars` to output your string.
You should use the flag `ENT_NOQUOTES` in the `$flags` argument to prevent it from converting quotes to html sequences.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem by escaping string...

Try this:

`$str = "<select name='image' OnChange='javascript:document.forms[0].showimage.src=" . $imgdir . " +this.value>";`

Comment: If you share what is your warning or error, maybe i can help you with some idea.